# Why is echo "bar" -n different from echo -n "bar"?

Tags: command-line

Compare

```
echo -n "bar"
```

with

```
echo "bar" -n
```

The former does what *I* think it's supposed to do (prints "bar" without a newline), while the latter doesn't. Is this a bug or by design? Why is it different than many cli programs in that you can't move the options around? For example, `tail -f /var/log/messages` is exactly the same as `tail /var/log/messages -f`. I sometimes do the latter when I forget I wanted the former, because internally the options and arguments are rearranged, usually by [getopt](http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt.html).

**Update:** yes I originally nerf-ed my question. I removed the nerf you'll have to view history to make some of the answers make sense.

Comment: From what I see, the difference *is* immediately obvious. `echo -n "bar"` gives "bar", while `echo "bar" -n` gives "bar -n"

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As most others have observed, "-n" is interpreted literally if placed anywhere but immediately after the `echo` command.

Historically, UNIX utilities were all like this -- they looked for options only immediately after the command name.  It was likely either BSD or GNU who pioneered the more flexible style (though I could be wrong), as even now [POSIX specifies the old way as correct](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap12.html#tag_12_02) (see Guideline 9, and also [`man 3 getopt`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getopt) on a Linux system).  Anyway, even though most Linux utilities these days use the new style, there are some holdouts like `echo`.

`Echo` is a mess, standards-wise, in that there were at least [two fundamentally conflicting versions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html#tag_20_37_18) in play by the time POSIX came into being.  On the one hand, you have SYSV-style, which interprets backslash-escaped characters but otherwise treats its arguments literally, accepting no options.  On the other, you have BSD-style, which treats an initial `-n` as a special case and outputs absolutely everything else literally.  And since `echo` is so convenient, you have thousands of shell scripts that depend on one behavior or the other:

```
echo Usage: my_awesome_script '[-a]' '[-b]' '[-c]' '[-n]'
echo -a does a thing.
echo -b does something else.
echo -c makes sure -a works right.
echo -- DON\'T USE -n -- it\'s not finished! --
```

Because of the "treat everything literally" semantic, it's impossible to even add a new option to `echo` without breaking things.  If GNU used the flexible options scheme on it, hell would break loose.

Incidentally, for best compatibility between Bourne shell implementations, [use `printf` rather than `echo`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html#tag_20_37_16).

**UPDATED** to explain why `echo` in particular does not use flexible options.

Comment: upvote since you're the only one to mention that's the expected getopt behavior.

Comment: @jander why is echo a "holdout"? I think it's a gnu coreutil?

Comment: @xeno: I've updated my answer.  Basically, GNU didn't want to break things.

Comment: One should also note that even if you have GNU coreutils, `echo` is usually implemented as a shell builtin and you will be using that--not that it really changes anything said above.

Comment: Accepting options after the first non-option is specific to [GNU](http://www.gnu.org/software) utilities and program using [GNU libc](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/)'s [getopt](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt.html) facilities. The user can always get backward-compatible behavior by setting the environment variable `POSIXLY_CORRECT`.

Comment: For the specific case of `echo`, there are also implementations that recognize `-e` or `-E` as options. For portability, don't start with a `-` or use something like `printf %s -e`.

Answer (score 9):

The other answers get to the point that you can look at the man page to see that -n is becoming part of the string to echo.  However I just want to point out that it's easy to investigate this without the md5sum and makes what's going on a little less cryptic.

```
[11:07:44][dasonk@Chloe:~]: echo -n "bar"
bar[11:07:48][dasonk@Chloe:~]: echo "bar" -n
bar -n
```

Comment: +1 exactly.  If a pipeline isn't doing what you expect, test each part separately.

Answer (score 6):

Wow, everyone's explanations are lengthy.

It's this simple:

`-n` is an option if it appears before the string, otherwise it's just another string to be echoed.

Remove the `| md5sum`  and you'll see the output is different.

Answer (score 5):

From simple inspection, this is not a bug by design...

```
echo "bar" -n | md5sum

a3f8efa5dd10e90aee0963052e3650a1
```

Try this command for yourself:

```
echo "bar -n" | md5sum
```

You will notice that the resulting md5 is

```
a3f8efa5dd10e90aee0963052e3650a1
```

You just mixed-up the use of -n in echo.

In your first sample code

```
echo -n "bar" | md5sum
```

-n is used to say DO NOT to put a newline after this echo.

Your second sample

```
echo "bar" -n | md5sum
```

is treating -n as a literal text.